# python fastest algorithm to get the most common prefix out of a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I need a function:

```
def get_prefix(list_of_strings):
  # Should give me the most common prefix
  # out of the given list_of_strings
  # of the lowest order of time possible
```

Also with the subsequent calls it should be possible to get the second most common prefix and so on. The prefix should be discarded if its length is lower than a global variable say `min_length_of_prefix`

#### Eg:

```
['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'not_a_file_1', 'not_a_file_2']
min_length_of_prefix = 6
first call: 'not_a_file_'
second call: None
```

---

```
['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'not_a_file_1', 'not_a_file_2']
min_length_of_prefix = 4
first call: 'file_'
second call: 'not_a_file_'
third call: None
```

Comment: This is more a description of your goal than a question.  Is there a problem with your current code we could help you with?  Is it buggy?  Too slow?  Etc.

Comment: @RoadRunner sorry for that, editing my question, it should be `not_a_file_`

Comment: @DSM yes I am dealing with large data sets and the first working program I made, I did it the pretty basic way, first look up for the max frequency of first character, then the next character is chosen such that it covers the max amount of strings but dealing with too many conditions over here. If I add more characters number of strings satisfying the prefix decreases and it soon becomes fuzzy whatever I am trying to do

Comment: Can we assume that the list of strings is already sorted? Since you want different values for each call, should the routine be a generator rather than a function? Also, if you show one of your code attempts you would avoid the suspicion that your are trying to get others to do your work.

Comment: @RoryDaulton no you can't except if the algorithm works at the same or greater magnitude of time than the sorting. I will edit the question and add my attempt to solving this.

Comment: can you define: *Large dataset* ?

Comment: @hootnot I guess large enough so that even after using multiprocessing, it takes over 7 mins to compute with my attempts

Comment: @RoadRunner yeah sure but the question is that your list can be infinitely big

Comment: @RoadRunner its a part of a much larger code base. Please wait and let me create an MVP, currently something's messing up with multiprocessing

Comment: @RoadRunner Posting bare *idownvotedbecau.se* link is [never recommended.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361377/6622817)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for this.

Insertion of each string takes `O(n)` (n = length of string).
And finding all prefixes within the minimum length is done by running a DFS on the tree.

Here's how I implement it. It returns a list of pairs `(prefix, frequency)` of all prefixes that are at least `min_length_of_prefix` characters long (in descending order of frequency).

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, character):
        self.count = 1
        self.character = character
        self.children = {}

    def insert(self, string, idx):
        if idx >= len(string):
            return

        code = ord(string[idx])
        ch = string[idx]
        if ch in self.children:
            self.children[ch].count += 1
        else:
            self.children[ch] = Node(string[idx])

        self.children[ch].insert(string, idx+1)

class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node('')

    def insert(self, string):
        self.root.insert(string, 0)

    # just a wrapper function
    def getPrefixes(self, min_length):
        # pair of prefix, and frequency
        # prefixes shorter than min_length are not stored
        self.prefixes = {}

        self._discoverPrefixes(self.root, [], min_length, 0)

        # return the prefixes in sorted order
        return sorted(self.prefixes.items(), key =lambda x : (x[1], x[0]), reverse= True)


    # do a dfa search on the trie
    # discovers the prefixes in the trie and stores them in the self.prefixes dictionary
    def _discoverPrefixes(self, node, prefix, min_length, len):
        # print(prefix)
        # print(node.count)
        if len >= min_length:
            self.prefixes[''.join(prefix)+node.character] = node.count

        for ch, ch_node in node.children.items():
            prefix.append(node.character)
            self._discoverPrefixes(ch_node, prefix, min_length, len+1)
            prefix.pop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    strings = ['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'not_a_file_1', 'not_a_file_2']

    min_length_of_prefix = 6

    trie = Trie()

    for s in strings:
        trie.insert(s)

    prefixes = trie.getPrefixes(min_length_of_prefix)

    print(prefixes)
```

Output:

```
[('not_a_file_', 2), ('not_a_file', 2), ('not_a_fil', 2), ('not_a_fi', 2), ('not_a_f', 2), ('not_a_', 2), ('not_a_file_2', 1), ('not_a_file_1', 1), ('file_3', 1), ('file_2', 1), ('file_1', 1)]
```

Comment: If it wasn't for your solution, I wouldn't have even thought of using a DAG like this! Thanks, you inspired me and I was sufficiently able to modify your solution to make one of my own. Also grouping prefixes with their frequencies

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list first, so that we can use `itertools.groupby` to group by each string's first character as a prefix, and for every group with more than one member, concatenate the character with every prefix returned by recursively calling the same `get_prefix` function with the rest of the string, unless there's no more prefix returned, in which case an empty string is returned. The number of members in every group at every level of recursion is also returned with the prefix as a tuple, so that in the end we can use it as a key for sorting to ensure the more common prefixes come first.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
list_of_strings = ['file_4', 'not_a_f', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'not_a_file_1', 'not_a_file_2']
def get_prefix(l, m):
    if not l: return []
    if m is not None: l.sort()
    r = [(k + p, f or len(g)) for k, g in [(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(l, itemgetter(0))] if len(g) > 1 for p, f in get_prefix([s[1:] for s in g if len(s) > 1], None)] + [('', 0)]
    if m: return sorted([(p, f) for p, f in r if len(p) >= m], key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return r
print(get_prefix(list_of_strings, 4))
print(get_prefix(list_of_strings, 6))
```

This outputs:

```
[('file_', 4), ('file', 4), ('not_a_f', 3), ('not_a_', 3), ('not_a', 3), ('not_', 3), ('not_a_file_', 2), ('not_a_file', 2), ('not_a_fil', 2), ('not_a_fi', 2)]
[('not_a_f', 3), ('not_a_', 3), ('not_a_file_', 2), ('not_a_file', 2), ('not_a_fil', 2), ('not_a_fi', 2)]
```

Comment: if `not_a_f` is appended to the input, shouldn't your output change? It doesn't p.s. I haven't looked closely to your algorithm

Comment: @IshanSrivastava I now see what your requirement really is. I've updated my answer accordingly. Please take another look. By using recursion the code can be made both more concise and efficient.